# Parsing XML from URL that has no doc type: Whats the error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

**EDIT:** My mistake the problem is I wasn't url encoding the string, ie xdoc.Load(Server.UrlEncode("website.com") );

In C# ASP.NET I am retrieving XML from a URL. The XML is in the format like so:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body> 
     <product>
        <course>
        </course>
     </product>
     ... more data
  </body>
</html>
```

So its really HTML or at best **Not valid XML**. I am getting an error when I go to load this xml which is from a server on the internet.

**Is the parsing/loading failing because the XML is not valid(HTML), or is it failing because I am retrieving XML from a URL instead of local file?**

**How can I sucessfully parse this file? Do I need to add a XML doc type, do I use a C# HTML parser?**

The error is:

```
// ERROR: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

    public string getProductXML()
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load("http://www.website.com/test.aspx?a=1&b=2"); //ERROR HERE: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
        // NOTE www.website.com is a different server to where this code is executing
        XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("group");


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the correct XML? Try downloading it manually e.g. using `WebClient` and then `LoadXml()` the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to using .Net 3.5, I would recomend using Linq2Xml.  Using Linq2Xml, I would use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download the source then use [XElement.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714.aspx) to parse the html (XElement.Parse() does not require the XML start tags).